# Коммиты в сабмодуле в git

Tags: git, git-commit, git-submodule

Есть проект yyy, внутри него сабмодуль xxx. Я работаю только с xxx, т.е. только сабмодулем. После выполнения таски коммичу и пушу изменения, находясь в папке сабмодуля. Нужно ли подыматься выше, коммитить и пушить весь проект, а не только сабмодуль?

Answer (score 3):

После публикации (push) изменений в подпроекте (submodule), нужно в основном проекте поменять "указатель" на версию подпроекта.

Пример:

```
 # посмотрим куда ведёт текущая ссылка на модуль
 проект$ git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep 'модуль'
 160000 commit 02148269395c1bc239c9db78a80dd85fc836a4dd модуль

 # опубликуем изменения в модуле
 проект$ pushd модуль
 проект/модуль$ git add myfile.c
 проект/модуль$ git commit -m "..."
 проект/модуль$ git push
 проект/модуль$ 

 # увидим, что ссылка в основном проекте всё ещё прежняя
 проект/модуль$ popd
 проект$ git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep 'модуль'
 160000 commit 02148269395c1bc239c9db78a80dd85fc836a4dd модуль

 # обновим ссылку из проекта в модуль
 проект$ git add модуль
 проект$ git commit -m "новая, улучшенная версия модуля"
 проект$ git push

 проект$ git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep 'модуль'
 160000 commit 5c2591854c69c6512232be4b2adffa70ef9ed944 модуль
```